# Why can I not change my variable amount and set it in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a pong game, and I am trying to add scores to it. It is not adding scores, no matter what I do. There is nothing in console. I couldn't find anything on google for it. Since the source code is very long, I will just paste the link. Here is the Html & Js:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Pong</title><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcanvas/21.0.1/min/jcanvas.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="center">
      <h1>Pong</h1>
      <span class="playeronescore"> Player 1 - <p id="playeronescore">0</p></span>
      <canvas id="gameScreen" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas>
      <br><br><span class="playertwoscore"> Player 2 - <p id="playertwoscore">0</p></span>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    var playeronescore = document.getElementById("playeronescore");
    var playertwoscore = document.getElementById("playertwoscore");
    scoreone = 0;
    scoretwo = 0;
    var PIXEL_RATIO = (function() {
      var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr =
          ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.backingStorePixelRatio ||
          1;

      return dpr / bsr;
    })();

    changeCanvasRatio = function() {
      const ratio = PIXEL_RATIO;
      const can = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
      can.style.width = can.width + "px";
      can.style.height = can.height + "px";
      can.width = can.width * ratio;
      can.height = can.height * ratio;
      can.getContext("2d").setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
      return can;
    };

    //Create canvas with the device resolution.
    changeCanvasRatio();
    
let canvas = $("#gameScreen");
const canvasBounds = { bottom: 600, top: 0, left: 0, right: 1000 };
let paddle1 = { height: 150, width: 22, x: 15, y: 225, vy: 0 };
let _paddle1 = Object.assign({}, paddle1);
let paddle2 = { height: 150, width: 22, x: 963, y: 225, vy: 0 };
let _paddle2 = Object.assign({}, paddle2);
let ball = { height: 15, width: 15, x: 492.5, y: 292.5, vx: 0, vy: 0 };
let _ball = Object.assign({}, ball);
let timer = 0;

let keys = { w: false, s: false, up: false, down: false };
const paddleSpeed = 6;
const initialBallSpeed = 5;
const ballSpeedIncrement = 1.6;
const startTimer = 100;

function resetGame() {
  timer = startTimer;

  paddle1 = Object.assign({}, _paddle1);
  paddle2 = Object.assign({}, _paddle2);
  ball = Object.assign({}, _ball);

  let ballDirection = Math.random() * 360;
  while (
    !(
      ballDirection < 60 ||
      (ballDirection > 120 && ballDirection < 240) ||
      ballDirection > 300
    )
  ) {
    ballDirection = Math.random() * 360;
  }

  ball.vx = convertToRect(initialBallSpeed, ballDirection).x;
  ball.vy = convertToRect(initialBallSpeed, ballDirection).y;
}

function convertToPolar(x, y) {
  let distance = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  let radians = Math.atan2(y, x);
  if (radians < 0) radians = (2 * Math.PI + radians) % (2 * Math.PI); // converts to positive
  let degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
  return { distance: distance, degrees: degrees };
}

function convertToRect(distance, degrees) {
  let radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
  let x = Math.cos(radians) * distance;
  let y = Math.sin(radians) * distance;
  return { x: x, y: y };
}

function checkCollision(paddle, object) {
  return (
    paddle.x < object.x + object.width &&
    paddle.x + paddle.width > object.x &&
    paddle.y < object.y + object.height &&
    paddle.y + paddle.height > object.y
  );
}

$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  switch (event.key) {
    case "w":
      keys.w = true;
      break;
    case "s":
      keys.s = true;
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      keys.up = true;
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      keys.down = true;
      break;
  }
});

$("body").keyup(function(event) {
  switch (event.key) {
    case "w":
      keys.w = false;
      break;
    case "s":
      keys.s = false;
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      keys.up = false;
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      keys.down = false;
      break;
  }
});

$("canvas").blur(function() {
  keys.w = false;
  keys.s = false;
  keys.up = false;
  keys.down = false;
});

function render(progress) {
  const p = progress / (1000 / 60);
  canvas.clearCanvas();

  canvas.drawRect({
    fillStyle: "#000000",
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: canvasBounds.right,
    height: canvasBounds.bottom,
    fromCenter: false
  });

  canvas.drawRect({
    fillStyle: "#FFFFFF",
    x: paddle1.x,
    y: paddle1.y,
    width: paddle1.width,
    height: paddle1.height,
    fromCenter: false
  });

  canvas.drawRect({
    fillStyle: "#FFFFFF",
    x: paddle2.x,
    y: paddle2.y,
    width: paddle2.width,
    height: paddle2.height,
    fromCenter: false
  });
  canvas.drawRect({
    fillStyle: "#FFFFFF",
    x: ball.x,
    y: ball.y,
    width: ball.width,
    height: ball.height,
    fromCenter: false
  });

  if (timer > 0) {
    timer--;
    return;
  }

  if ((keys.w && keys.s) || !(keys.w || keys.s)) {
    paddle1.vy = 0;
  } else if (keys.w) {
    paddle1.vy = -1 * paddleSpeed;
  } else if (keys.s) {
    paddle1.vy = paddleSpeed;
  }

  if ((keys.up && keys.down) || !(keys.up || keys.down)) {
    paddle2.vy = 0;
  } else if (keys.up) {
    paddle2.vy = -1 * paddleSpeed;
  } else if (keys.down) {
    paddle2.vy = paddleSpeed;
  }

  paddle1.y += paddle1.vy * p;
  paddle2.y += paddle2.vy * p;

  ball.x += ball.vx * p;
  ball.y += ball.vy * p;

  if (paddle1.y > canvasBounds.bottom - paddle1.height) {
    paddle1.y = canvasBounds.bottom - paddle1.height;
    paddle1.vy = 0;
  }
  if (paddle1.y < canvasBounds.top) {
    paddle1.y = canvasBounds.top;
    paddle1.vy = 0;
  }

  if (paddle2.y > canvasBounds.bottom - paddle2.height) {
    paddle2.y = canvasBounds.bottom - paddle2.height;
    paddle2.vy = 0;
  }
  if (paddle2.y < canvasBounds.top) {
    paddle2.y = canvasBounds.top;
    paddle2.vy = 0;
  }

  if (ball.y > canvasBounds.bottom - ball.height) {
    ball.y = canvasBounds.bottom - ball.height;
    ball.vy *= -1;
  }
  if (ball.y < canvasBounds.top) {
    ball.y = canvasBounds.top;
    ball.vy *= -1;
  }
  if (ball.x < canvasBounds.left || ball.x + ball.width > canvasBounds.right)
    resetGame();
  
  if (ball.x <= canvasBounds.left) {  
    scoreone += 1;
    playeronescore = scoreone;
  }
  if (ball.x + ball.width >= canvasBounds.right) {
    scoretwo += 1;
    playertwoscore = scoretwo;
  } 
  
  if (checkCollision(paddle1, ball)) {
    ball.x = paddle1.x + paddle1.width + 0.01;
    ball.vx *= -1;
    const polar = convertToPolar(ball.vx, ball.vy);

    let ballDirection = polar.degrees;
    let ballSpeed = polar.distance;

    ballSpeed += ballSpeedIncrement;

    ballDirection += 90;
    if (ballDirection > 360) ballDirection -= 360;

    const ballDistance =
      ball.y - (paddle1.y + paddle1.height / 2 - ball.height);
    const percentChange =
      (50 / (paddle1.height / 2)) * Math.abs(ballDistance) * 0.01;
    1;
    if (ballDistance < 0) {
      ballDirection *= 1 - percentChange;
    } else {
      ballDirection = 180 - ballDirection;
      ballDirection *= 1 - percentChange;
      ballDirection = 180 - ballDirection;
    }

    if (ballDirection < 90) ballDirection += 360;

    ballDirection -= 90;

    const _temp = convertToRect(ballSpeed, ballDirection);
    ball.vx = _temp.x;
    ball.vy = _temp.y;
  }

  if (checkCollision(paddle2, ball)) {
    ball.x = paddle2.x - ball.width - 0.01;
    ball.vx *= -1;
    const polar = convertToPolar(ball.vx, ball.vy);

    let ballDirection = polar.degrees;
    let ballSpeed = polar.distance;

    ballSpeed += ballSpeedIncrement;

    ballDirection -= 90;

    const ballDistance =
      ball.y - (paddle2.y + paddle2.height / 2 - ball.height);
    const percentChange =
      (50 / (paddle2.height / 2)) * Math.abs(ballDistance) * 0.01;

    if (ballDistance > 0) {
      ballDirection *= 1 - percentChange;
    } else {
      ballDirection = 180 - ballDirection;
      ballDirection *= 1 - percentChange;
      ballDirection = 180 - ballDirection;
    }

    ballDirection += 90;

    const _temp = convertToRect(ballSpeed, ballDirection);
    ball.vx = _temp.x;
    ball.vy = _temp.y;
  }
}
    
resetGame();

let lastRender;
function loop(timestamp) {
  const progress = timestamp - lastRender;

  render(progress);

  lastRender = timestamp;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

lastRender = 0;
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);   
    
  </script>
</html>
<script type="application/javascript" src="/share.js"></script>
```

view-source:https://aaryank.codewizardshq.com/Pong1/pong.html

Comment: You need to post relevant code here and show what you've debugged so far.  Your width calculations are not correct.

Comment: @user120242 What do you mean my width calculations are not correct? What do I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting the game before you check who wins.  And you have to use innerHTML to write to the contents of the DOM element.  What you are doing is just assigning the variable `playertwoscore` to the value of scoretwo.  setting
Faulty code is here:

```
 if (ball.x <= canvasBounds.left) {  
    scoretwo += 1;
    document.getElementById('playertwoscore').innerHTML = scoretwo;
  }
  if (ball.x + ball.width >= canvasBounds.right) {
    scoreone += 1;
    document.getElementById('playeronescore').innerHTML = scoreone;
  } 
  if (ball.x < canvasBounds.left || ball.x + ball.width > canvasBounds.right)
    resetGame();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcanvas/21.0.1/jcanvas.js" integrity="sha256-ZqFgz7QUEDRCvHiosY/FIao3Zg5Pmg2J4rlLTEWu4BI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Pong</title><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcanvas/21.0.1/min/jcanvas.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="center">
      <h1>Pong</h1>
      <span class="playeronescore"> Player 1 - <p id="playeronescore">0</p></span>
      <canvas id="gameScreen" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas>
      <br><br><span class="playertwoscore"> Player 2 - <p id="playertwoscore">0</p></span>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    var playeronescore = document.getElementById("playeronescore");
    var playertwoscore = document.getElementById("playertwoscore");
    scoreone = 0;
    scoretwo = 0;
    var PIXEL_RATIO = (function() {
      var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr =
          ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.backingStorePixelRatio ||
          1;

      return dpr / bsr;
    })();

    changeCanvasRatio = function() {
      const ratio = PIXEL_RATIO;
      const can = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
      can.style.width = can.width + "px";
      can.style.height = can.height + "px";
      can.width = can.width * ratio;
      can.height = can.height * ratio;
      can.getContext("2d").setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
      return can;
    };

    //Create canvas with the device resolution.
    changeCanvasRatio();
    
let canvas = $("#gameScreen");
const canvasBounds = { bottom: 600, top: 0, left: 0, right: 1000 };
let paddle1 = { height: 150, width: 22, x: 15, y: 225, vy: 0 };
let _paddle1 = Object.assign({}, paddle1);
let paddle2 = { height: 150, width: 22, x: 963, y: 225, vy: 0 };
let _paddle2 = Object.assign({}, paddle2);
let ball = { height: 15, width: 15, x: 492.5, y: 292.5, vx: 0, vy: 0 };
let _ball = Object.assign({}, ball);
let timer = 0;

let keys = { w: false, s: false, up: false, down: false };
const paddleSpeed = 6;
const initialBallSpeed = 5;
const ballSpeedIncrement = 1.6;
const startTimer = 100;

function resetGame() {
  timer = startTimer;

  paddle1 = Object.assign({}, _paddle1);
  paddle2 = Object.assign({}, _paddle2);
  ball = Object.assign({}, _ball);

  let ballDirection = Math.random() * 360;
  while (
    !(
      ballDirection < 60 ||
      (ballDirection > 120 && ballDirection < 240) ||
      ballDirection > 300
    )
  ) {
    ballDirection = Math.random() * 360;
  }

  ball.vx = convertToRect(initialBallSpeed, ballDirection).x;
  ball.vy = convertToRect(initialBallSpeed, ballDirection).y;
}

function convertToPolar(x, y) {
  let distance = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  let radians = Math.atan2(y, x);
  if (radians < 0) radians = (2 * Math.PI + radians) % (2 * Math.PI); // converts to positive
  let degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
  return { distance: distance, degrees: degrees };
}

function convertToRect(distance, degrees) {
  let radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
  let x = Math.cos(radians) * distance;
  let y = Math.sin(radians) * distance;
  return { x: x, y: y };
}

function checkCollision(paddle, object) {
  return (
    paddle.x < object.x + object.width &&
    paddle.x + paddle.width > object.x &&
    paddle.y < object.y + object.height &&
    paddle.y + paddle.height > object.y
  );
}

$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  switch (event.key) {
    case "w":
      keys.w = true;
      break;
    case "s":
      keys.s = true;
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      keys.up = true;
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      keys.down = true;
      break;
  }
});

$("body").keyup(function(event) {
  switch (event.key) {
    case "w":
      keys.w = false;
      break;
    case "s":
      keys.s = false;
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      keys.up = false;
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      keys.down = false;
      break;
  }
});

$("canvas").blur(function() {
  keys.w = false;
  keys.s = false;
  keys.up = false;
  keys.down = false;
});

function render(progress) {
  const p = progress / (1000 / 60);
  canvas.clearCanvas();

  canvas.drawRect({
    fillStyle: "#000000",
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: canvasBounds.right,
    height: canvasBounds.bottom,
    fromCenter: false
  });

  canvas.drawRect({
    fillStyle: "#FFFFFF",
    x: paddle1.x,
    y: paddle1.y,
    width: paddle1.width,
    height: paddle1.height,
    fromCenter: false
  });

  canvas.drawRect({
    fillStyle: "#FFFFFF",
    x: paddle2.x,
    y: paddle2.y,
    width: paddle2.width,
    height: paddle2.height,
    fromCenter: false
  });
  canvas.drawRect({
    fillStyle: "#FFFFFF",
    x: ball.x,
    y: ball.y,
    width: ball.width,
    height: ball.height,
    fromCenter: false
  });

  if (timer > 0) {
    timer--;
    return;
  }

  if ((keys.w && keys.s) || !(keys.w || keys.s)) {
    paddle1.vy = 0;
  } else if (keys.w) {
    paddle1.vy = -1 * paddleSpeed;
  } else if (keys.s) {
    paddle1.vy = paddleSpeed;
  }

  if ((keys.up && keys.down) || !(keys.up || keys.down)) {
    paddle2.vy = 0;
  } else if (keys.up) {
    paddle2.vy = -1 * paddleSpeed;
  } else if (keys.down) {
    paddle2.vy = paddleSpeed;
  }

  paddle1.y += paddle1.vy * p;
  paddle2.y += paddle2.vy * p;

  ball.x += ball.vx * p;
  ball.y += ball.vy * p;

  if (paddle1.y > canvasBounds.bottom - paddle1.height) {
    paddle1.y = canvasBounds.bottom - paddle1.height;
    paddle1.vy = 0;
  }
  if (paddle1.y < canvasBounds.top) {
    paddle1.y = canvasBounds.top;
    paddle1.vy = 0;
  }

  if (paddle2.y > canvasBounds.bottom - paddle2.height) {
    paddle2.y = canvasBounds.bottom - paddle2.height;
    paddle2.vy = 0;
  }
  if (paddle2.y < canvasBounds.top) {
    paddle2.y = canvasBounds.top;
    paddle2.vy = 0;
  }

  if (ball.y > canvasBounds.bottom - ball.height) {
    ball.y = canvasBounds.bottom - ball.height;
    ball.vy *= -1;
  }
  if (ball.y < canvasBounds.top) {
    ball.y = canvasBounds.top;
    ball.vy *= -1;
  }
  
  if (ball.x <= canvasBounds.left) {  
    scoretwo += 1;
    playertwoscore.innerHTML = scoretwo;
  }
  if (ball.x + ball.width >= canvasBounds.right) {
    scoreone += 1;
    playeronescore.innerHTML = scoreone;
  } 
  if (ball.x < canvasBounds.left || ball.x + ball.width > canvasBounds.right)
    resetGame();
  
  if (checkCollision(paddle1, ball)) {
    ball.x = paddle1.x + paddle1.width + 0.01;
    ball.vx *= -1;
    const polar = convertToPolar(ball.vx, ball.vy);

    let ballDirection = polar.degrees;
    let ballSpeed = polar.distance;

    ballSpeed += ballSpeedIncrement;

    ballDirection += 90;
    if (ballDirection > 360) ballDirection -= 360;

    const ballDistance =
      ball.y - (paddle1.y + paddle1.height / 2 - ball.height);
    const percentChange =
      (50 / (paddle1.height / 2)) * Math.abs(ballDistance) * 0.01;
    1;
    if (ballDistance < 0) {
      ballDirection *= 1 - percentChange;
    } else {
      ballDirection = 180 - ballDirection;
      ballDirection *= 1 - percentChange;
      ballDirection = 180 - ballDirection;
    }

    if (ballDirection < 90) ballDirection += 360;

    ballDirection -= 90;

    const _temp = convertToRect(ballSpeed, ballDirection);
    ball.vx = _temp.x;
    ball.vy = _temp.y;
  }

  if (checkCollision(paddle2, ball)) {
    ball.x = paddle2.x - ball.width - 0.01;
    ball.vx *= -1;
    const polar = convertToPolar(ball.vx, ball.vy);

    let ballDirection = polar.degrees;
    let ballSpeed = polar.distance;

    ballSpeed += ballSpeedIncrement;

    ballDirection -= 90;

    const ballDistance =
      ball.y - (paddle2.y + paddle2.height / 2 - ball.height);
    const percentChange =
      (50 / (paddle2.height / 2)) * Math.abs(ballDistance) * 0.01;

    if (ballDistance > 0) {
      ballDirection *= 1 - percentChange;
    } else {
      ballDirection = 180 - ballDirection;
      ballDirection *= 1 - percentChange;
      ballDirection = 180 - ballDirection;
    }

    ballDirection += 90;

    const _temp = convertToRect(ballSpeed, ballDirection);
    ball.vx = _temp.x;
    ball.vy = _temp.y;
  }
}
    
resetGame();

let lastRender;
function loop(timestamp) {
  const progress = timestamp - lastRender;

  render(progress);

  lastRender = timestamp;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

lastRender = 0;
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);   
    
  </script>
</html>
<script type="application/javascript" src="/share.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh ok I understand now. I was resetting the game before I check who wins. Ok +1